# Calling WCF service from host

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I am hosting a WCF service library in an ASP.net web application, which also needs to consume it. What is the best way to do so? Should I create a client proxy and invoke the service that way or is there a way of directly calling it? (the library is a project reference after all, and I guess doing so would be faster)

Answer (score 3):

Since your WCF service library is a project reference for your web application, you could just instantiate the service directly without creating a client proxy.  This approach would indeed be faster since you wouldn't be going through the serialization and deserialization that WCF does.  However, you may wish to create a client proxy and access the service that way.  This approach would be useful if there's any chance you may at some point host the service outside of your web application.  If you were to end up moving the service, you would just need to update the endpoint address in your web application's web.config file.